# Java Application, Set connection Timeout to 0

Tags: java

I have a java application, it tries to connect to a particular website.
But however, my internet does not let it connect, is there a way to set the Connection Timeout to 0 so it does not waste time tring to connect?

Comment: time out to 0 is same as not trying to connect, you can reduce the time out but it depends on how do you connect and for that you need to show code

Comment: You would have to tell us how you are connecting. Also, generally, you may want a small value, but you don't want 0 (it does take time to connect under normal circumstances).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the connection timeout to zero all right via the API, but that doesn't mean zero time, and, contrary to what it says in the Javadoc, it doesn't mean an infinite timeout either: it means the platform default, which is around a minute.

In any event zero time is too short: no connection can complete in zero time. You can set it low, say a second, which might be enough on some networks. You'll have to experiment to get a reasonable value.

Comment: As in, how would I make it like this,

Try connection for around 10 miliseconds if there is no connection , stop trying to connect.